# How can we modify all of the human bone items in Skyrim?

Tags: skyrim-modding

I have the models, but I am wondering which object_id I need to modify. Is there a single object_id for every skeleton part, or each parts have several variants and several object_id? Is there a list with all of the skeleton parts in the game thereby allowing me to modify all of the vanilla models without having to worry about not having changed all of the skeleton models in the game?